# Reading data from a specific line and counting words from nth line to print nth word on that line

Tags: java

I have this program that reads a text file. I need to get some data out of it.
The text files look like this:

```
No.     Ret.Time    Peak Name   Height  Area    Rel.Area    Amount  Type 
    min     µS  µS*min  %   mG/L    
1   2.98        Fluoride    0.161   0.028   0.72        15.370  BMB
2   3.77        Chloride    28.678  3.784   99.28       2348.830    BMB
Total:          28.839  3.812   100.00      2364.201
```

I need to start reading from line #29 and from there get the Peak Name and the Amount of each element like Fluoride, Chloride and so on. The example only shows those two elements, but other text files will have more. I know I will need some sort of loop to iterate through those lines starting on line #29 which is where the "1" starts then the "2" which will be the 30th line and so on.

I have tried to make this work, but I am missing something I think and I`m not sure what. Here is my Code.

```
int lines = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
String word = null;

while((word =br.readLine()) != null){
    lines++;
    /*if(lines == 29)
    System.out.println(word);*/

    if ((lines == 29) && sc.hasNext())
    count++;
    String value = sc.next();
    if (count == 2)
    System.out.println(value + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code for you:

```
int linesToSkip = 28;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (linesToSkip-- > 0) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] values = line.split(" +");

        int index = 0;
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println("values[" + index + "] = " + value);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've surrounded it in a `try(expr) {}` block to ensure that the reader is closed at the end, otherwise you'll consume resources and possibly lock the file from other processes.

I've also renamed the variable you called `word` as `line` to make it clearer what it contains (i.e. a string representing a line in the file).

The `line.split(" +")` uses a regular expression to split a String into its constituent values. In this case your values have spaces between, so we're using `" +"` which means 'one or more spaces'. I've just looped through the values and printed them out; obviously, you will need to do whatever it is you need to do with them.

I replaced the line count with a `linesToSkip` variable that decrements. It's less code and explains better what you're trying to achieve. However, if you *need* the line number for some reason then use that instead, as follows:

```
if (++lineCount <= 28) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly, you are mixing two different readers with the `BufferedReader` and the `Scanner`, so you are not going to get the results right changing from one to the other (one is not pointing to the same position than the other). You already have the line in `word` and you can parse it, no need of using the `Scanner`. Just skip until line 29 (`lines > 29`) and then parse the values you want, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file twice... try something like this

```
    int lines = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (++lines < 29)
            continue; //this ignores the line

        for(String word : line.split("separator here")) {
            // this will iterate over every word on that line
            // I think you can take it from here
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
```